# Dynamic Input mask using the county DAC on the customer screen

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I am trying to set my Input mask at runtime according to the country that is selected.

I created the following DAC to save the Input mask:

```
namespace PX.Objects.CS
{
  public class CountryExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CS.Country>
  {
    #region UsrPhoneMask
    [PXDBString(50)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Phone Mask")]

    public virtual string UsrPhoneMask { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrPhoneMask : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrPhoneMask> { }
   #endregion
  }
}
```

The part I am struggling with is when I Override the attribute on-screen level, this is the Phone1 field on the Customer screen:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true,
    InputMask = Search<CountryExt.usrPhoneMask, Where<Country.countryID,Equal<Current<Country.countryID>>>>]

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Phone 1", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    // [PhoneValidation()]
    [PXMassMergableField]
    [PXPersonalDataField]
    protected virtual void Contact_Phone1_CacheAttached(PXCache cache){ }
  }
}
```

I know it is the search I am implementing wrong just don't know how to fix it.

I have also tried setting it using a const

```
    public const string Masknum = PXSelect<CountryExt.usrPhoneMask, Where<Country.countryID, Equal<Current<Country.countryID>>>>;
    public class masknum : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<masknum>
    {
        public masknum() : base(Masknum) {; }
    }
    PXSelect<CountryExt.usrPhoneMask, Where<Country.countryID,Equal<Current<Country.countryID>>>>;

    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = Masknum)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Phone 1", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    // If you do not remove below attribute the mask will not be set
    // [PhoneValidation()]
    // [PXMassMergableField]
    [PXPersonalDataField]
    protected virtual void Contact_Phone1_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Property values declared in DAC attribute are not dynamic because they are required to be constant values by .NET Framework compilers. To change the mask at runtime you should investigate the `ReturnState` property of `CacheAttached` and `FieldSelecting` events.

From the `Source Code` page (SM204570) you can search for the `OrderSiteSelectorAttribute` which implements a dynamic mask using these methods.
[image]

Other examples shipped in the product source code might be more useful for your use case so you can also do a broad search for `ReturnState`. Here's the relevant code shown in the screenshot above:

```
public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
    base.CacheAttached(sender);

    PXDimensionAttribute attr = new PXDimensionAttribute(SiteAttribute.DimensionName);
    attr.CacheAttached(sender);
    attr.FieldName = _FieldName;
    PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e = new PXFieldSelectingEventArgs(null, null, true, false);
    attr.FieldSelecting(sender, e);

    _InputMask = ((PXSegmentedState)e.ReturnState).InputMask;
}

public override void SubstituteKeyFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    base.SubstituteKeyFieldSelecting(sender, e);
    if (_AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Item || e.IsAltered)
    {
        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, null, null, null, null, null, _InputMask, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

From the matching DAC `RowSelected` event, try calling the `SetInputMask` method.
If that is producing the expected results it is the most straightforward way to achieve dynamic input mask:

```
PXStringAttribute.SetInputMask<DAC.field>(sender, inputMaskValue);
```